# Keystore error when trying to run android calabash tests

Tags: android, testing, rubymine, calabash, android-keystore

I'm trying to run some `calabash` tests in RubyMine, to test a previously build .apk file.

When I try to run all features, the following error message pops up. I built the .apk file with AndroidStudio, not specifying a certain keystore, so I guess the "default" `debug.keystore` is used.

```
No MD5 fingerprint found:
  Keytool Error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: X:/.android/debug.keystore
java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: X:/.android/debug.keystore
  at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:738)
  at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
  at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
(RuntimeError)
```

As far as I know the provided keystore for testing has to be the same as the one used when building the .apk, which should be the `debug.keystore` in my `.android` folder, since its the only one present on my computer.

I'm not sure why `keytool` tries to find the keystore file on the `X:/` drive instead of the `D:/` drive where the `debug.keystore`exists.

Is there any way to tell `keytool` (or RubyMine) which keystore to use? Or may there be another problem I'm not aware of? Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Note: I was able to run the tests when using an older .apk. Only when I did some changes in the android code and build the app again the error occurred when trying to run the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We try to autodetect the keystore. You can just use calabash-android setup to specify your keystore. Run the command from your test working directory.

Comment: when running `calabash-android setup` I only get the usage prompted but nothing further, any ideas on that?